# How to call a stored procedure using asp classic?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, asp-classic

I am using sql server and asp classic, and am currently calling queries like this:

```
newHireSQL = "select * from NewHire where Archived = 0 order by HireID desc"

Set rsGetHireID = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rsGetHireID.Open newHireSQL,ConnectionString,adOpenStatic

NumOfHireID = rsGetHireID.RecordCount
```

But instead of having the query statement here, I want to call a stored procedure called `dbo.sp_selectNewHireSQL`. How can I do that?

Thanks

EDIT:

I tried this

```
Dim Conn
SET Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
SET rsGetHireID = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
Conn.Open ConnectionString
set rsGetHireID=Conn.Execute("Exec sp_selectNewHireSQL")

NumOfHireID = rsGetHireID.RecordCount
Response.Write (NumOfHireID)
```

But I am getting a `-1` value for the record count.

Answer (score 3):

It's just use `exec` or `execute` statement:

```
Set Conn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.Open ConnectionString
Conn.Execute "Exec sp_selectNewHireSQL"
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: I updated my original post with your suggestion, but I am getting a -1 for the record count.

Answer (score 3):

To have the RecordCount working you need to use proper cursor:

```vbs
Set rsGetHireID = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
Conn.Open ConnectionString
rsGetHireID.CursorLocation = 3 'adUseClient
rsGetHireID.Open "Exec sp_selectNewHireSQL", Conn
NumOfHireID = rsGetHireID.RecordCount
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `ADODB.Connection`, try using `ADODB.Command` instead like this:

```
        Set objCommand = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
        objCommand.ActiveConnection = ConnectionString
        objCommand.CommandText = "dbo.sp_selectNewHireSQL"
        objCommand.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc ' you have to include adovbs.inc file or you can use 4

        Set rsGetHireID = objCommand.Execute()
        NumOfHireID = rsGetHireID.RecordCount
        Response.Write (NumOfHireID)
```

Comment: Where is the parameter being passed to the stored procedure?  I see a parameter (with a value of 0) in the original SQL string:

newHireSQL = "select * from NewHire where Archived = 0 order by HireID desc"

Answer (score -4):

```
<%


    dim db_conn

   db_conn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Server=server name;Database=dbname;Uid=sa; Pwd=123;"
set conn = server.createobject("adodb.connection")
set Cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
'-------------------------------------------------------
conn.open (db_conn)
'-------------------------------------------------------
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")  
sSQL = "EXEC sp_countrylist @countryname ='" & countryname & "'"
set rs = conn.execute(sSQL) 

if (rs.bof and rs.eof) then
    response.Write "<span class=""error"">No Record Found</span>"
    response.End
end if %>
```

Comment: Bad answer. This exposes you to Sql injection.